# Exception android.graphics.BaseCanvas.onHwBitmapInSwMode

Tags: java, android, crash, crash-reports

Play store giving this stackstrace.

This crash occur in some device have **Version(8.1 and 9.0)**. But If I test manually, it can't be reproduce.

I have searched a lot. But not found any solution.

**Some Device List**

- Vivo v7
- Vivo v7+
- Vivo Y81
- Samsung J6 , J7, A30, Note 8
- Redmi Note 5 pro
- MI A1
- ......More

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   at
>   android.graphics.BaseCanvas.onHwBitmapInSwMode (BaseCanvas.java:593) 
>   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfHwBitmapInSwMode
>   (BaseCanvas.java:600)  at
>   android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw (BaseCanvas.java:80)  at
>   android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawBitmap (BaseCanvas.java:140)  at
>   android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap (Canvas.java:1504)  at
>   android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw
>   (BitmapDrawable.java:545)  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw
>   (ImageView.java:1342)  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21869)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21737)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at
>   android.view.ViewOverlay$OverlayViewGroup.dispatchDraw
>   (ViewOverlay.java:251)  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21884) 
>   at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21737)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21872)  at android.view.View.draw
>   (View.java:21737)  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild
>   (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw
>   (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at android.view.View.draw (View.java:21872)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21737)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21735)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21735)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild (ViewGroup.java:4553)  at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw (ViewGroup.java:4328)  at
>   android.view.View.draw (View.java:21872)  at
>   com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw (DecorView.java:1082)  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware (ViewRootImpl.java:4059)  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw (ViewRootImpl.java:3958)  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw (ViewRootImpl.java:3700)  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3011) 
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:1874)  at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run
>   (ViewRootImpl.java:8491)  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:949)
>   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:761)  at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:696)  at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run
>   (Choreographer.java:935)  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback
>   (Handler.java:873)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   (Handler.java:99)  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7058)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:493)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:964)